# How to add password to localdb

Tags: sql-server-express, localdb

Anybody know how I can update my "Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=SampleDB" to require a password so I can pass it in via connection string? I'm using .NET core, C# with Visual Studio building a simple app that uses localdb that currently only works with 'Trusted_Connection=True' in the connection string.

I want to update the db to require a password that I can pass via connection string.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to check is mixed mode authentication enabled in this instance of SQL Server. To do this, run Management Studio and connect to the server. Right click on the server in Object Explorer and click Properties. From the dialog shown, go to Security and make sure "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" is selected:

[image]

You need this mode to be able to authenticate with user name and password. It can be enabled using T-SQL script too:

```
ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE;
GO  
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '<enterStrongPasswordHere>';  
GO
```

At this moment (and eventually restarting of your instance) you should be able to use sa login name and password in your connection string. However this isn't recommended. It will be much better to create a dedicated login (other than sa) for your application. You can do this from Object Explorer in Security \ Logins section, or with script:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [my_login] WITH PASSWORD=N'<enterStrongPasswordHere>', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[YourDatabaseName], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO
```

Then you need to make a user for this login in your database (logins are server's level objects, users are in the database). Run this script:

```
USE [YourDatabaseName]
GO
CREATE USER [my_login] FOR LOGIN [my_login]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [my_login]
GO
```

This will give your login full rights over your database. You may want to grant it less rights, only what is needed, but I do not know what do you actually need. I will recommend you to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authorization-and-permissions-in-sql-server) article to get some idea what and how to do.

After you do all of that, you can use connection string like that:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;User id=my_login;Password=<enterStrongPasswordHere>;
```